# Can I lose a companion if his approval goes too low?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Since it was the case in the previous Dragon Age and since it's no longer possible to keep track precisely of the level of approval of my companions. Do I risk to lose any of them and if yes who ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra, Varric and Solas, who you meet first and are essential to the story, will never leave you no matter how much they disapprove. Every other companion will leave you if their approval gets too low.

Answer (score 0):

According to bioware if you lose too much approval the companion will leave and even betray you if you go to far. They even said its possible to finish the game with one companion(likely cassandra since she's part of the war council)

Comment: Do you have any source for that ?